Cannot see the Solution Explorer References node in VSTA project
We are building SSIS applications in Visual Studio 2022. When editing an SSIS Script Task Visual Studio launches a VSTA project instance.
Normally the project will look something like this:

However, when a fellow developer does this, he sees this:

The Properties and References nodes are missing from the Solution Explorer and although the ScriptMain.cs does show in the code window - if you close it you cannot get it back.This occurs both in new, and existing projects/packages.
This problem does NOT occur in normal Visual Studio projects of other types - for this developer.

We have tried switching the TargetServerVersion setting on the package, and it happens with both SQLServer2019, and SQLServer2022 settings.

We have tried re-installing both the SQL Server Data Tools, and the "SQL Server Integration Services Projects 2022" for Visual Studio.

We have tried repairing the "Visual Studio for Applications 2022"

We have tried playing with the "Switch between solutions and available views" button on the Solution Explorer.


All my googling attempts have come up empty. Has anyone seen this issue before, and/or have an idea about how to get around it?

So, we sent tech support requests to Microsoft on this issue - twice. They ignored us for a long time, and finally responded basically saying that since no one else has reported this issue - they are not going to address it. Thanks!
The solution was to completely unistall Visual Studio (not just SSIS), and reinstall everything. My guess is that there was an another instance of Visual Studio (possibly installed by another user) that may have conflicted with the current install. The reason we think that is because on one of the un-install screens it said something like "Visual Studio (2)" - possibly indicating that there were 2 instance of VS on the computer. Just a guess. Once we cleared everything off and reinstalled - it worked.
